# What is a2-a1 : b3-b1 in this AP?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

```
X  a1  a2  Y
X b1 b2 b3 Y
```

what is a2-a1 : b3-b1 in this AP? i was getting an answer of 2/3. don't know if it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

$a_2 - a_1 = \frac{1}{3} (Y-X)$ and $b_3 - b_1 = \frac{1}{2} (Y-X) $.